# Ms Access Sql Inner Join partial match of two columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables with one column each and the strings in the table.column named copy2.col2 has only some of the middle text of table copy1.col1

Here's my sql: ...It doesn't retrieve any matches but at least no syntax errors either.

```
SELECT copy1.col1, copy2.col2
FROM copy1 INNER JOIN copy2 ON copy1.col1 ="*"&copy2.col2&"*";
```

The question is - what's wrong - it doesn't retrieve any records?
I have partial strings in both columns so that I at least know that It's working (in case I got the Join backwards)

Thanks in advance - Ken

Comment: whats the stars (*) for? Are you trying to say copy1.col1 contains cop2.col2 in your query?

Comment: The text above didn't paste correctly.   Here is what I tried to paste:   SELECT copy1.col1, copy2.col2
FROM copy1 INNER JOIN copy2 ON copy1.col1 ="*"&copy2.col2&"*";

Comment: the stars are supposed to be wildcards

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do write this type of query is using the sql `LIKE` keyword with the sql multicharacter wildcard character: `%`. Try this:

```
SELECT copy1.col1, copy2.col2
FROM copy1 INNER JOIN copy2
ON copy1.col1 LIKE '%' & copy2.col2 & '%';
```

But don't expect great performance since this type of query can't use an index and therefore will do a full table scan.

Comment: Basically, I know a little about MS Access and I use it a lot but I'm not very good at it.   I have two columns of data.  One column has the original model numbers and the other has the same models but some extra text added to both ends and I'm trying to match these together.   It doesn't have to be this particular query but somehow I've gotta get these two columns matched up.  Thanks

Comment: Depending on where and how you're running the query, you may need to substitute `*` for the `%` wildcards: `ON copy1.col1 LIKE '*' & copy2.col2 & '*'`

Comment: Thanks.  The wildcards work, It just returns col1 and col2 as empty or no matches.   If I eliminate the wildcards and just enter LIKE copy2.col2;   I get all the exact matches (there are some exact matches in the tables) - no problem but I can't get the partial match thing to work.  thx